# How to use heaps with dictionaries to implement single source shortest path algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I chose to represent my graph as a nested dictionary:

```
graph = {'A': {"B": 20, 'D': 80, 'G' :90},
        'B': {'F' : 10},
        'F':{'C':10,'D':40},
        'C':{'D':10,'H':20,'F':50},
        'D':{'G':20},
        'G':{'A':20},
        'E':{'G':30,'B':50},
        'H':{}}
```

And from a previous question, I was instructed to use heaps to implement the dijkstra single source shortest paths algorithm. The problem is that after I checked the docs of the heap, it turns out that I can't use it directly with a dictionary, but with a list. How do I do that? What is wrong in my solution?

Comment: What does not work with your code? Do you ger an error? Is the result wrong?

Comment: @Tichodroma I actually I need to access the dictionary to get the edges from the graph and then implement them on heaps, but I don't know how to do that. My piece of code eventually gives the shortest edge in the entire graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a heap even if it requires a list. `graph.keys()` returns a list of keys in your dictionary. The heap can then be built using the keys and if you need to find vertexes, dictionary lookup can be used.

`vertexes = graph[heap.pop()]`.